# Communication btw collectionViews in tableViewCells. This tableView is in another tableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have horizontal scrolling collectionViews.  They are nested inside a tableView bc I want independent horizontal scrolling.

This is a card-game thing.  So there are 4 rows of 13 cards.

The problem is, I need to control how many items the user can select across all four collection views.

I also need to get what items have been selected back to the main viewController.  I don't really know how to go about doing this.

A custom tableViewCell is the datasource and delegate for the collectionView.

I also need to know the value of the selected cells.  Thanks guys, this is a bit of a mess.  But I have the UI that I want.  Just have to make it work for the UX now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UICollectionViewDelegate` to get the `didSelectItemAt` event to know when a `UICollectionViewCell` is selected.

Then you can create your own Delegate method, or Closure, to send the selected item from the `UITableViewCell` to the `UIViewController`.
On the `UIViewController` you can now manage and update the number of selected cards, and update the `UITableViewCells` to allow/deny any other selections on their `UICollectionView`.